# Javascript binding switch's case to a html button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, switch-statement

I've been trying to make a button that would invoke a JavaScript case from switch. The script I tried to create was supposed to calculate square's perimeter and area but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type=text id="num"><br>
<input type="button" value="area" id="abut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="per" id="pbut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
</form>
<script>
function calc(count) {
    var a =parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    var w;
    if isNaN(a) {
        alert("Input a number");
    }
    else {
        switch(count) {
            case 'area' :
                w=a*a;
                break;
            case 'per' :
                w=a*4;
                break;
        }
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = w;
    }
}
</script>
<p id="res"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo error: `if isNaN(a)` must be between parenthesis. It should be `if (isNaN(a))`

```js
function calc(count) 
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    var w;

    if (isNaN(a)) 
    {
        alert("Input a number");
    } 
    else 
    {
        switch (count) 
        {
            case 'area':
                w = a * a;
                break;
            case 'per':
                w = a * 4;
                break;
        }

        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = w;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type=text id="num">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="area" id="abut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
    <input type="button" value="per" id="pbut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
  </form>
  <p id="res"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put brackets around condition in `if` statement.

```
  if isNaN(a)
```

should be

```
  if (isNaN(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>
function calc(count)
{
var a =parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
var w;
if (isNaN(a))
{
alert("Input a number");
}
else
{
switch(count)
{
case 'area' :
w=a*a;
break;
case 'per' :
w=a*4;
break;
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = w;
}}
</script>

</head>
<form>
<input type=text id="num"><br>
<input type="button" value="area" id="abut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="per" id="pbut" onclick=" return calc(this.value)">
</form>
<p id="res"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, please?

Comment: As you can see the difference: `if isNaN(a)` changed to `if (isNaN(a))`.  Whenever you feel fishy in scripting, just open developer tools in browser, this developer tool clearly shows such syntactic errors. In google Crome: more tools -> developer tools.